ts-morph error: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'computed'
I wrote my own component library based on element-pls. When generating types, I got an error. All exports related to vue could not be found.
Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'onMounted'.
Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'ref'.
Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'computed'.

import {
    projRoot,
    pkgRoot,
    buildOutput,
    excludeFiles,
    epRoot
} from '@hfn-components/build-utils'
import {resolve, relative} from "path";
import { Project } from "ts-morph";
import * as vueCompiler from "vue/compiler-sfc";
import glob from "fast-glob";
import {readFileSync} from 'fs'
import type { CompilerOptions, SourceFile } from 'ts-morph'
import consola from 'consola'
const TSCONFIG_PATH = resolve(projRoot,"tsconfig.json")
const outDir = resolve(buildOutput, "types");


export const generateTypesDefinitions = async () => {
  const compilerOptions: CompilerOptions = {
    emitDeclarationOnly: true,
    outDir,
    baseUrl: projRoot,
    preserveSymlinks: true,
    skipLibCheck: true,
    noImplicitAny: false,
  }

  const project = new Project({
    compilerOptions,
    tsConfigFilePath: TSCONFIG_PATH,
    skipAddingFilesFromTsConfig: true,
  })

  const sourceFiles = await addSourceFiles(project)
  consola.success('Added source files')

  typeCheck(project)
  consola.success('Type check passed!')

  await project.emit({
    emitOnlyDtsFiles: true,
  })

  const tasks = sourceFiles.map(async (sourceFile) => {
    consola.log(sourceFile.getFilePath())
    // const relativePath = relative(pkgRoot, sourceFile.getFilePath())
  })
}



// await addSourceFiles(project);
async function addSourceFiles(project:Project) {
  project.addSourceFileAtPath(resolve(projRoot, 'typings/env.d.ts'))
  const globSourceFile = "**/*.{js?(x),ts?(x),vue}";
  console.log('---',globSourceFile)
  const filePaths = excludeFiles(
    await glob([globSourceFile, '!hfn-components/**/*'], {
      cwd: pkgRoot, 
      absolute: true, 
      onlyFiles: true, 
    })
  );
  const epPaths = excludeFiles(
    await glob(globSourceFile, {
      cwd: epRoot, 
      onlyFiles: true, 
    })
  );
  console.log("filePaths", filePaths);
  console.log("epPaths",epPaths)
  const sourceFiles: SourceFile[] = []
  await Promise.all([
      ...filePaths.map((file) => {
        if (file.endsWith(".vue")) {
          const content = readFileSync(file, "utf-8");
          const sfc = vueCompiler.parse(content);
          const { script, scriptSetup } = sfc.descriptor;
          if (script || scriptSetup) {
            console.log()
            let content = script?.content ?? "";
            if (scriptSetup) {
              const compiled = vueCompiler.compileScript(sfc.descriptor, {
                id: "xxx",
              });
              content += compiled.content;
            }
            console.log(content)
            const lang = scriptSetup?.lang || script?.lang || "js";
            const source = project.createSourceFile(
                `${relative(process.cwd(), file)}.${lang}`,
                content
            );
            sourceFiles.push(source)
          }
        } else {
          const source = project.addSourceFileAtPath(file);
          sourceFiles.push(source)
        }
      }),
      ...epPaths.map(async (file) => {
        const content = readFileSync(resolve(epRoot, file), "utf-8");
        sourceFiles.push(project.createSourceFile(resolve(pkgRoot, file), content))
      }),
    ]);

    return sourceFiles
}



function typeCheck (project: Project){
  const diagnostics = project.getPreEmitDiagnostics()
  if (diagnostics.length > 0) {
    consola.error(project.formatDiagnosticsWithColorAndContext(diagnostics))
    const err = new Error('Failed to generate dts.')
    consola.error(err)
    throw err
  }
}

My SFC uses setup syntax sugar, Vue version 3.4.29
If I install @vue/runtime-core dependency, exporting from this dependency will work. If I import ref from @vue/runtime-core, the error won't appear.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.
